# In Moscow, who can be inoculated with the Sputnik V vaccine?

Tags: covid-19, russia, moscow, vaccinations

On German TV, there are reports that in the shopping mall [GUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUM_(department_store)) (ГУМ) in central Moscow anyone who walks in and shows a passport can be inoculated with the Russian Sputnik V vaccine against COVID-19.

Could anyone (maybe living in Moscow) confirm this is really true for *everybody*? Or would they ask for proof of Russian residency for example? Basically, if I am in Moscow on a business trip, can I go there and get vaccinated?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more about asking if a specific situation taking place presently is really true.

Comment: @Mark Johnson If we closed questions on that basis, we’d be closing a lot. It might be more valid to close it on the basis that the answer may only be correct for a brief time, but that applies to many other Covid-related questions too. On balance I think it should stay open.

Comment: @Traveller There are various international reports on this topic, all of which seem vague on details. Not sure if this type of report is actually realistic or just trying to send out another message. [2021-01-18: Russia launches mass coronavirus vaccination campaign - France 24](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20210118-russia-launches-mass-coronavirus-vaccination-campaign), [2021-01-24: Russland: Corona-Impfung mit "Sputnik V" jetzt in Kaufhäusern und Oper](https://www.businessinsider.de/wissenschaft/gesundheit/russland-corona-impfung-mit-sputnik-v-jetzt-in-kaufhaeusern-und-oper-b/)

Comment: @Traveller [2021-01-24: As Others Rush to Vaccinate, Moscow Lures Takers With Ice Cream - Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-01-30/as-others-rush-to-vaccinate-moscow-lures-takers-with-ice-cream).

Comment: 2020-10-28: **Ministry of Health denies the possibility of vaccination of foreigners against coronavirus for money**: 'Vaccination against COVID-19 on a commercial basis, **and even for tourists**, is not possible. Vaccinations are already underway, and for citizens it is free. **Russians have absolute priority in vaccination**. And only after satisfying the internal need, when the risk groups and all those who wish are vaccinated, it will be possible to talk about some kind of commercial supplies' said Mr. Kuznetsov [TASS](http://tass.ru/obschestvo/9833373)

Comment: Since, as of 2021-01-11, only about 1% of Russia’s 146 million population have been vaccinated, one should assume that the **only after satisfying the internal need** condition of the Russian *Ministry of Health* was not fullfilled when these news reports came out last week. [Russia Says It Has Vaccinated 1.5M. Some Experts Think the Numbers Don’t Add Up. - The Moscow Times](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2021/01/14/russia-says-it-has-vaccinated-15m-some-experts-think-the-numbers-dont-add-up-a72602). Such news reports should be considered, at best, **misleading**.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, a *russian internal* passport is needed to get a vaccine. (A passport in Russia can mean two separate documents: an internal passport, used as the main person ID inside Russia, and which naturally proves your Russian citizenship, and a foreign-travel passport where you get your visas to. When someone says simply "passport", they usually mean the former.)

In particular, recently there was a [news report](https://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/60100d609a79477eb41f6b08) that one of largest Russian taxi and food delivery service, Yandex.Taxi, asks the government to allow vaccinating of their drivers and couriers working in Moscow who are foreign citizens (there are a lot of drivers and couriers in Moscow who are citizens of other former Soviet republics), and this news also explicitly says that vaccination currently is available only to Russia citizens.

Comment: A reliable source, that this 'offer' is available only to Russia citizens (or residents) would be welcomed. That might discouraged some who may think it is a good idea to hop on a plane to Moscow, only to find after arrival that they are not eligible.

Comment: I'm a Moscow resident, can confirm you need an internal passport to get a COVID-19 shot. There are plans to give shots to permanent residents and some foreign workers but it all seems to be up in the air at this point.

Comment: @MarkJohnson https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/4549677 might be the reliable source you're looking for. The first paragraph states that the Ministry of Health denies the possibility of vaccinating foreign tourists, for money or otherwise, at the time. The article then describes some illegal schemes of COVID shot "tourism" purportedly performed or planned. While those rumors might be true, such "tourism" is certainly illegal and could potentially result in various charges, risk of being duped, and other ramifications, and is therefore not recommended.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, it seems that it's rather difficult to find any up-to-date reliable and clear sources. For example, when writing the answer I was trying to find out whether Russian citizens from other regions, not Moscow, can get a vaccine in Moscow, and couldn't get any clear information on this question. Also, the situation changes rapidly. For example, even several weeks ago the vaccination was available only to people employed in several specific job areas, and a proof of employment in such areas was needed (though reportedly not checked). So I would not trust any pre-mid-Jan information.

Comment: I confirm first-hand that Russian citizens from outside Moscow can get a vaccine in Moscow, using the public vaccination facilities, starting from January 18, 2021.

Comment: The text at [mos.ru](https://www.mos.ru/city/projects/covid-19/privivka/) is vague, but it mentions that vaccination is available for the general public from January 18.