# Sputnik V vaccine for non-Russians

Tags: covid-19, russia, vaccinations, medical-tourism

As more Russian citizens are vaccinated and the country ramps up its production, is there any possibility that Sputnik V will become available for those traveling to Russia?  Or, as an alternative, will its international distribution be broadened so that people may travel to other countries to receive this vaccine?

Comment: Are you open to traveling to the US? Tourists can get one there if they're otherwise eligible.

Comment: @JonathanReez they can get the Sputnik vaccine in the US??

Comment: @MarkMayo I meant they can get Pfizer, Moderna or J&J there.

Comment: Distant relative: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162338/45949

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I travel to receive a COVID vaccine as a tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161569/where-can-i-travel-to-receive-a-covid-vaccine-as-a-tourist)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that currently nominally you [will have to be](https://medsi.ru/lands/vaktsinatsiya-ot-novoy-koronavirusnoy-infektsii-covid-19-v-medsi.php) a citizen of Russia, have residence permit (вид на жительство) or be a part of a diplomatic mission.

There are reports that [foreign citizens are vaccinated without problems](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/4694519), in practice. Think if you want to bet on that.